# How to find what causes Windows 10 to boot slowly

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance, logging

My Windows 10 boots very slowly. At startup it remains stuck on the boot image with no hard disk working for 1-2 minutes; after that it starts normally.

I've already checked if I have "fast boot up" option active, but I don't have that option.

So my question is: how to find what program/service causes this lag?

[image]

Comment: Check BIOS to see the boot order, and make 'Windows Boot Manager' the 1st priority if it is not on top.